# Weird texture placement

Tags: texturing, uv

I don't know how to name it, but my texture of sand has weird placement
I am new to Blender and i have no clue how to fix that.
[image]

Comment: The UV map node (on the left) has no UV map indicated. Also you should get a picture showing the UV map defined for your object.

Comment: I was following this guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3CqkHstRA1A